# Angular route guard always redirects to app component only

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a guard which should run on every route. If user is logged in, they should be redirected to dashboard else to login. Login works fine but auth guard never redirects to dashboard. it always stays in base route. If i manually redirect to dashboard from guard it causes an infinite loop.

**app-routes.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: AppComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
];
```

**AuthGuard.ts**

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private _router: Router, private _loaderService: LoaderService) {
  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    _state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    this._loaderService.show();
    this.authService.isLoggedIn().subscribe( (_allowed: boolean) => {
      if (_allowed) {
        this._loaderService.hide();
        console.info('authenticated', next, _state);
        // this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']); // this cause infinite loop if uncommented
        return true;
      } else {
        console.info('not authenticated');
        this._loaderService.hide();
        this._router.navigate(['/login'], {
          queryParams: {
            return: _state.url
          }
        });
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
}
```

**AuthService.ts**

```js
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.token) {
      return this._httpClient.get(environment.api_url + `/api/auth/` + this.token)
        .pipe(map((_response: any) => {
          this._user.updateUser(_response.data);
          this.updateToken(_response.token);
          return _response.status;
        }));
    } else {
      return of(false);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your public route shouldn't be a child of a protected route.

Move the public route at the root of your routes, and you should be good to go.

Comment: sorry didn't get you, by public route you mean moving the dashboard route out of the blank path right? i want auth guard to run for every route for that i have to define every route as a child of the blank route. also i tried i moving the dashboard route out it still stays in base root only. after authenticating it doesnot redirect to dashboard.

Comment: Yes, dashboard out of the group. If you don't have any public route, then you can't redirect to a route, since your guard will prevent every route from being shown. You need at lease a public route, let it be dashboard, login, home, or whatever you want. If you encounter an unknown issue, it's usually a good idea to provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try implementing CanActivateChild also -

```
canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
return this.canActivate(route, state);
}
```